# Efficiently to NOT EXSISTS when query in documentDb?

Tags: performance, nosql, azure-cosmosdb

Let's say we have two collection, a User collection and a Item Collection.

User collection, each User document store the purchase product ids of the user.

```
{
 "id" : "UserA",
 "PurchasedProductId" : ["ProductId1", ... "ProductIdNN"]
}
```

Item collection, each Item document store the product information.

```
{
 "Id" : "ProductId1" 
}
```

I want the query will returns the top 10 items of the item collection, ordered by the last updated time, plus, if the user already purchased the item before, the query should skip the user purchased item and return the non-purchased item only.

In MsSQL we could simply do NOT EXISTS, how do we do it efficiently in documentDB?

How do we do it in documentDB?

I can imagine of course we can pass like

```
SELECT * WHERE (c.id != id1 && c.id != id2 && ..... c.id != idNNNN) LIMIT 10
```

But really, if the every user has purchased over 500 items, is this even efficient?

What is the efficient way to do it?

Comment: Does the purchase product ids store in the user collection as an array? Please give sample format of your documents  in collections?

Comment: @JayGong I don't know what is other way instead of storing in array.  Actually my question is open to change any structure into to make it efficient.  How should i store the data in order to make it perform the NOT EXISTS perform well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my [research](http://www.nikoport.com/2018/03/07/cosmosdb-api-support-3ps-particular-partial-percentages/), `Exist` and `NOT Exists` have not supported in the cosmos db query so far. So, I suggest you using stored procedure to get the results you want.

***sample stored procedure:***

```
function sample(alreadyPurchaseIdsArray) {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();

    //var alreadyPurchaseIdsArray = ["1","2","3"]

    var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(
    collection.getSelfLink(),
        'SELECT top 10 c.id FROM c ',
    function (err, feed, options) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (!feed || !feed.length) {
            var response = getContext().getResponse();
            response.setBody('no docs found');
        }else {
            var response = getContext().getResponse();
            var returnResult = [];
            for(var i = 0;i<feed.length;i++){
                if(alreadyPurchaseIdsArray.indexOf(feed[i].id) == -1)
                returnResult.push(feed[i]);
                getContext().getResponse().setBody(returnResult);
            }
        }
        });

        if (!isAccepted) throw new Error('The query was not accepted by the server.');
}
```

`alreadyPurchaseIdsArray` is passed into stored procedure as parameter.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that is the best way if I have to do it in documentDb